# MVC bind IEnumerable List Of Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a model that contains an ienumerable list of SIte Data
I am trying to figure out how to bind it and pull it on a page load and form post

SiteServices is an intersection table  to a Servicers table
but the relationship is 1 to 1

```
public Class Site {
  public int SiteID {get;set;}
  public string Desc {get;set;}
  public IList<SiteServices> SiteServices {get;set;}
}
```

View using

```
@HTML.DropDownListFOr(model => 
   model.siteServices,(SelectedList) ViewBag.ServicesList,"Select a Service Area")
```

Comment: You are trying to bind your selected item to an IList, which isn't going to work.  Your List of items should be an enumerable of some kind, but your selected item must be a single item that is selectable in a form, like a string or int.

Answer (score 1):

try to bind your model on the View and create another variable to hold the selected service

```
public Class Site {
   public int SiteID {get;set;}
   public string Desc {get;set;}
   public string SiteService {get;set;}
   public IList<SiteServices> SiteServices {get;set;}
}
```

on your View

```
@HTML.DropDownListFOr(model => model.SiteService, Model.SiteServices, "Select a Service Area")
```

Comment: I am now allowed to modify the model that exists